# Mongoose query from two schemas that share same reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have two schemas:
1. UserEnrolledCourses

```
var userCoursesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users'},
    courseId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'courses'},
    isEnrolled: Boolean,
});
```

2.  CourseResources

```
var resourcesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    courseId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'courses', required: true },

    type: {type:String, required:true},

});
```

Both of them shared the same `courseId` reference from `courses` schema.
So, my aim is to generate result from query that for each courseId that one user enrolled, list all of the resources that available. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

In mongoDB, you are performing queries on one concrete collection. The only exception is the left outer join with new method $lookup in aggregation for mongodb 3.2 and more. Look at [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)